# php imagemagick does not work after successful installation on mac

Tags: php, macos, imagemagick, imagick, php-extension

I need to make `imagemagick` workable in on mac. My mac version is `macOS Sierra`. I did the following steps:

1. `brew install ghostscript`
2. `brew install imagemagick`
3. `brew install php70-imagick` since I use php7.0
4. Then write the location of `imagick.so` in `php.ini` that is
   `extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php70-imagick/3.4.3_2/imagick.so`
5. then restarted apache, i.e. `sudo apachectl restart`
6. then run `php -r "print(class_exists('Imagick'));"` I can see it prints `1`.

Now when run the following code, it prints `echo 'Imagick is not installed';`

```
if( class_exists("Imagick") )
{
    echo 'Imagick is installed';
}
else{
    echo 'Imagick is not installed';
}
```

I do not understand how I can enable `imagemagic` in my `localhost` of mac or where I did wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you edited the right php.ini? It seems that you edited the CLI php.ini and not the webserver (apache or whatever you use) php.ini.

Comment: I have edited at `/etc/php.ini`. Isn't it right?

Comment: If I am correct that is the file for the CLI (you can check with `php --ini` in Terminal). Could you try and use `phpinfo()` in an actual file (not CLI) and see where that php.ini file is located?

Comment: I see it @/etc/php.ini in `phpinfo`.

Comment: Well, then I don't know what to do. I can only suggest you restart your Mac.

Comment: I did it couple of time too. really frustrated!!

Comment: I think you need to edit `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and add in a line like this `LoadModule php5_module    /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` except adapt it for `php7`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I had already added this `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`. Should I add like you yet?

Comment: You need to tell **Apache** to use the **PHP** that **homebrew**  installed, so first you will need to edit an **Apache** config file such as `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and second, you will need to put something in there that refers to the PHP module in `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/local/Cellar` which is where **homebrew** puts stuff rather than referring to something in `/libexec` which is where macOS puts stuff.

Comment: I do understand well your comment. If it is possible, could you give me an answer with some detail. thanks

Comment: What command did you use to install `PHP7`? Was it `brew install php70` or `brew install php70 --with-httpd24`.

Comment: perhaps `brew install php7`. I did it many days ago. so I forget.

Comment: If you installed IM 7, then I do not think Imagick is compatible with it, yet. Try installing IM 6 and see if that works.